# MaskedEditText input to string

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hi I have imported a dependency from gitHub that set's a mask on a Input. But I can't seem to get the input and convert it to string. I do that by trying to diplay it using textview from this activity.

**Activity_Violator.java**

```
public class ViolatorDetail2 extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitiy_violator_detail2);
    MaskedEditText maskedEditText = (MaskedEditText)findViewById(R.id.masked_edit_text);
    final String a =maskedEditText.getText().toString();

    Button btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
    btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMaskTry);
            b.setText(a);
        }
    });
```

It only returns the ' - - ' values from the mask on button click.

**XML file**

```
<com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/masked_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:mask="***-**-******"
    app:notMaskedSymbol="*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as I searchet the lib you are using it should be `MaskedEditText#getText().toString()`. But you should use it in your listener. Not in `onCreate` method.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please flag my answer as the correct one if it helped you.